# How to start a script on page load and then use setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function, timer() that I want to run once immediately on page load, and then to run every second thereafter.

At present I have the following code using setInterval:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var timer = function(){
    ...
}

timer();

setInterval(function(){
      timer();
}, 1000);
});
```

**Note, I don't just want to use setInterval alone, as this creates a 1sec delay after the page loads**

However, my use of timer(); seems to stop other script on the page working. Any ideas? No errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timerLoop;
    var timer = function(){
                ...
            timerLoop = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
        };
    timer();
}
```

Notice the `timerLoop` variable, which you can use to stop the "interval" (`clearTimeout(timerLoop);`) if needed.

[Timeouts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#windowtimers) are not really asynchronous, they are just timed. If there's another script running, a timed script is executed after the previous script has been finished.

I'd prefer `setTimeout()` instead of `seInterval()`, since the latter has a disadvantage: If there's another script blocking the execution of timed calls set by `setInterval()`, these calls are stacked, and when the blocking script is finished, all stacked calls are executed as fast as possible. Usually this is undesired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, this still prevents other scripts from loading though in .ready function?

Comment: Executing a timed script will block other scripts as well. If you are _loading_ scripts within a script, then the loading itself is done asynchrounously, but nothing will be executed before the current script is finished.

Comment: @alias51 To show you an example of how `setInterval()` differs from `setTimeout()` please check ["a-mess-fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/BKupY/3/) (with a non-IE-browser), visit another tab  for a while, and return to "a-mess-fiddle". Then do the same at ["working-fiddle"](http://jsfiddle.net/BKupY/5/), you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.log(timer)` and you will clearly see that it is a number, not a function you can call.

Instead, you have to manually call the function as well as set the timer.

```
function timer() {
    // do something
}
$(function() {
    timer();
    setInterval(timer,1000);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use repeated timeouts:

```
function timer() {
    // do something
    setTimeout(timer,1000);
}
$(timer);
```